# How can I access the remote WSDL provided by a webservice based on https in java code or ant-target?

Tags: java, https, wsdl, jax-ws

How can I access the remote WSDL provided by a webservice based on https in java code or ant-target?

In other words,I want to use the webservice in java code and jar the code generated by the wsimport.

Answer (score 0):

Please tak a look at: [Web Services made easy JAX-WS 2.0](http://today.java.net/article/2006/06/12/web-services-made-easy-jax-ws-20)